# _subscribers and All subscribers list

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, list-view, subscriber, view

I can find new records that are inserted in the _subscribers table but do not find the same subscribers in the All subscribers when I search for them using email address. How is that scenario possible. 
Isn't the _subscribers data extension a subset of All subscribers list?

Comment: Any more details on your account - do you have multiple business units? Is it an ET 1.0 account?

Answer (score 1):

data views is a system table that stores subscriber information for **180 days**. .

The All subscribers list acts as the master publication list for your account, keeping track of all subscribers attributes, with an emphasis on status. The main reason for this is to honour unsusbcribes.

To get a like for like query of all subscribers, you would query _ListSubscribers WHERE ListID='63' (check the all subscribers list properties in your account for the listID)

Comment: What leads you to believe that _Subscribers only contains 6 months worth of data, but _ListSubscribers contains more than that? I don't believe there is any monthly limitation on these types of data views, it is only for subscriber events (send, open, click, etc.) that ET stops tracking on a 6 month rolling period.

Comment: @AnonWonderer missed this you are right miss type will correct now